# Useful APIs to Live Video Stream between Windows C# and Android Java?

Tags: java, c#, udp, live-streaming

Following [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35930309/why-my-udp-client-server-datagram-is-not-operating-the-two-way-communication/36191166#36191166) approach. I want a Client to Live Stream Video to a server using IP communication. Requirements are **Android Studio Java Client and Visual Studio C# Server** and this is why I didn't find exact situation on StackOverFlow. I set up a basic **UDP Datagram** between Android Java and Windows C# and it's up and running two-way sending short messages. **Where do I start with Video Streaming?**

Shall I figure it out myself how to get the images frame by frame in the server, break each frame into `byte[]` order them and send over using UDP, then in the client's side, rebuild each frame using `byte[]` data received? 
Is't fine to use UDP?
What are **useful APIs on both C# and Java**?
Is it going to be easier on the long run to set both as Java? 
Do I need time to adapt Windows Java IDEs now and start from there? Is it the same as Android?

Two many questions on my head and I don't have enough knowledge. I have never done "big" nor "networking" application before. I feel lost on what to do. Finding APIs would really be helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't invent your own protocols, use existing ones like RTP, RTSP (or even a HTTP server).

For instance RTSP (Real-Time Streaming Protocol):

With this project (https://net7mma.codeplex.com/), you're able to set up RTSP server which serves a media file in exactly 5 lines of Code in C#.

```
using(Rtsp.RtspServer server = new Rtsp.RtspServer(555)){    
    Media.Rtsp.Server.Media.RtspSource source = 
          new Media.Rtsp.Server.Media.RtspSource("RtspSourceTest", "rtsp://1.2.3.4/mpeg4/media.amp");

   //If the stream had a username and password
   //source.Client.Credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");

   //Add the stream to the server
   server.AddMedia(source);

   //Start the server and underlying streams
   server.Start();
}
```

And according to the project page:

> The RtspServer does successfully aggregate live Rtsp video streams in ANY container or codec to a compatible RtspClient or Player (VLC, Mplayer Darwin Streaming Server and QuickTime have been tested)
>
> This lets you turn your Web Camera or Digital Camera or source of images into a LIVE Rtsp Stream!

With this server side written in C# as a general RTSP server, you can use existing objects like a normal `VideoView` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10461150/5296568) on the Java/Android side to connect and view that live stream without problems.

Comment: Hi, this looks helpful and I am giving it a try. So the design is like the C# general RTSP server takes the webcam stream into a uri, then the Java side will just use that uri to view?

Comment: @FireStep Exactly, that's the top-level abstraction of it. And with the right libraries, it can really be done in just a few lines of code.

Comment: Thank you, sir. "right libraries" like the one you sent? Shall I drop all my base code and start building a C# RTSP server? I posted it would you please tell me your recommendations?

Comment: Your approach with sending UDP packets yourself is alright for *small applications*, where you just have to send one message or so. It would be really painfull to write your own streaming protocol that transports the video-data over UDP to another device yourself, that's why I recommend the use of existing protocols and the use of libraries, which give you an easy-to-use implementation of such a server. So yes, don't start micro-managing the UDP packets for the livestream yourself, think bigger. Get a RTSP server up and running with some mediasource and start connecting to its livestream.

Comment: Can you please add whatever knowledge you think would be helpful in my way approaching that, that you would also like to share?

Comment: Maximilian, Where is that URI going to be located? like.. the video will be saved locally on the laptop and then VideoView will access it using the laptops IP? How it's going to happen? and.. what is MediaSource? thanks

Comment: Can this approach be used for video chat?